# How to programmatically obtain Fabric/Crashlytics framework version?

Tags: ios, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Is it possible to programmatically obtain the installed version of Crashlytics/Fabric? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; see `Crashlytics.h`:

```
@interface Crashlytics : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *APIKey;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *version;     // !!!!!
@property (nonatomic, assign)         BOOL      debugMode;

...
```

So that would be:

```
NSLog(@"Using Crashlytics version %@", [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] version]);
```

Comment: Any idea on how to do it now that it's part of Firebase?

Comment: @agirault no idea soz