# How to programmatically get Crashlytics version with Firebase on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

With **Fabric**, it was the following (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32588762/3783833)):

```swift
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().version
```

With **Firebase**:

- the instance is `Crashlytics.crashlytics()`, but there is no version on it
- nothing of interest in [`FIRCrashlytics.h`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Crashlytics/Crashlytics/Public/FirebaseCrashlytics/FIRCrashlytics.h)
- Since `Crashlytics` is an `NSObject`, `Crashlytics.version` exists, but it's equal to 0.
- I also looked on the `FirebaseCrashlytics` module to no avail.

The Crashlytics version is actually printed in the console when running `FabricApp.configure` in the `AppDelegate`, so it's clearly defined somewhere, but I need to access it to display it in the app:

```
${time_stamp} ${app_name}[${process_id}] [Firebase/Crashlytics] Version 4.3.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API was added to Firebase/Crashlytics 7.1.0: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Functions#/c:@F@FIRFirebaseVersion

Swift:

```swift
FirebaseCore.FirebaseVersion()
```

Objc

```objectivec
FIRFirebaseVersion()
```

Answer (score 0):

Chintan from Firebase here. This has just been implemented in the latest version of Crashlytics iOS SDK (7.0.1). So from now on Crashlytics will use the same version as iCore, so here’s the API for it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Functions